# Dual NIC for internet security

Tags: wireless-networking

I want to set up a “box” between my wireless router and my WAN modem. I want to install Internet filtering software on it to control all computers on my LAN as well as firewall/antivirus software.

Can I use an old Windows system (XP for example) with two NICs? If so, would I need a program to control the NICs as to which is going to the WAN and which is going to the LAN?

I want to go from the wireless router to the “box” through the filtering software then out to the modem.

Answer (score 1):

> Can I use an old Windows system (XP for example) with two NICs?

Yes, you can create your own [gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residential_gateway).

> If so, would I need a program to control the NICs as to which is going to the WAN and which is going to the LAN?

No. Simply connect the network cable from/to the correct devices and NICs. Then you can configure the two network adapters as needed in *Control Panel->Network Connections*.

> I want to go from the wireless router to the “box” through the filtering software then out to the modem.

This is simple. You need to configure four things:

1. Configure the WAN-facing NIC to connect to the router as you would with just one directly connected to the modme.
2. Configure your LAN-facing NIC with an appropriate private IP and subnet mask, and set its gateway to the IP of the WAN-facing NIC.
3. Configure the router to use the private IP and subnet of the LAN-facing NIC.
4. For each system on the WAN, configure them to use the IP of the router as their gateway.

Answer (score 1):

While you could use an old XP box, you're better off using a router centric distro to handle the routing, such as [untangle](http://www.untangle.com/) or [vyatta](http://www.vyatta.org/), unless you absolutely need the box running windows XP. It'll be simpler, you'll have a much wider range of services and options - including everything you asked for, and  it'll be less vulnerable in many cases than an XP system - amongst other things, being based off an up-to-date OS.

Comment: Re: Untangle; Um, even the basic u10 is $1,000. A decent PC that can more than handle the job can be had for 1/10 that.   Re: Vyatta; when I was in university, one of my classmates bragged about using a Linux box as a gateway. I would assume Vyatta would be easier to configure and use since it is specifically meant for this purpose.

Comment: There's a free version you van run on your own PC of untangle - see the download as opposed to the appliance link - this will include the 'lite' version's apps, which covers the requirements in the original question.